# How to create file of files?

Tags: c#, .net, file

```
class Node
{
    FooType Data; // I can save Data to file with extension .foo
    void Save()
    {
       // save Data to .foo file
    }
}
```

Now ,

```
class Graph
{
    List<Node> Nodes; 
    void Save()
    {
        foreach(Node node in Nodes)
        {
            node.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I invoke `someGraph.Save();` then it creates `Nodes.Count` number of files.

I would like to appear those files as one file with extension `somename.graph` and be able to read it again as `Nodes`.

How can I do this? Is there a way to bundle files into a single different file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an archive format like [zip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Without external library support, you could just use .Net's serialisation mechanism to store a `Dictionary<string, byte[]>` (filename and data for each file) in a single file. Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Nice. But  am not allowed to use external libraries. +1 This is what I am thinking about but is there any other way?

Comment: What is "external" about it?  It's built into the .Net framework.

Comment: @Chris, that's probably my fault. The link I provided points to a third-party zip library. I wasn't aware that .Net has zip file support built in.

Answer (score 0):

Or Graph.Save should pass the file stream it is using to each of the node.Save calls, so Node.Save uses the same file stream as its enclosing Graph.

Comment: I have no control over `Data.Save();`. It will create `somthing.foo` on disk. I want to combine those `.foo`s to one single file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the classes in the System.IO.Compression namespace?  Specifically, GZipStream?  This would not constitute a 3rd party library as it is built into .Net and is available from 2.0 and onward.